# How to "chroot" a terminal inside a DMG?

Tags: terminal, command-line, dmg

I'm doing security research and for that purpose I use an SHA-2 encrypted DMG to store the tools and files I work with (containing confidential client info), to protect them from forensic examination of my hard drive.

Thinking further, I'd like to know how (if possible) I could open a shell environment    inside this mounted DMG, so my .bash_history, .ssh/config and keys and an ./sbin/ binaries folder are available from a shell but only when the DMG is mounted to protect the info they contain. I also hope to make it portable from mac to mac, with my tool and my key, on any mac on which I open the DMG.

Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Would it work to just create symlinks to the files in the mount point of the DMG?

Comment: That would leave traces of the presence of the tools outside the DMG, something I'd like to avoid.

Comment: If you want to leave absolutely no trace, the easiest option would probably be a VM…

Comment: @Zof, since the operating system sees a mounted DMG as just another volume, I'm wondering if you might have better luck asking this question over at Unix.  I'm going to suggest editing your question and migrating it over.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed what I wanted to do is over complicated. A VM is a better option.